# How to order 3 variables ascending in c++ using only if and else if

Tags: c++, variables

As the title says i need to sort 3 numbers ascending without using void swap etc.I can use else and if else.The 3 numbers don't need to be different for example we could have:
a-5,b-5,c-10 and the output should be -5 -5 10.I am doing this for an online learning program but my code gets me 93 points of 100 and because of this i can't jump to the next lesson. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;

    if ( a < b && b < c ) {
        cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
    } else if ( a > b && b > c ) {
        cout << c << " " << b << " " << a;
    }

    if ( a < c && b < a ) {
    cout << b << " " << a << " " << c;
    }

    if ( a < c && c < b ) {
        cout << a << " " << c << " " << b;
    } else if ( a > c && b > a ) {
        cout << c << " " << a << " " << b;
    }

    if ( a == b && b == c ) {
        cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
    } else if ( a == c && b == a ) {
        cout << b << " " << c << " " << a;
    }

    if ( a == b && c < a ) {
        cout << c << " " << b << " " << a;
    } else if ( a == b && c > a ) {
        cout << b << " " << a << " " << c;
    }

    if ( a == c && b < a ) {
        cout << b << " " << c << " " << a;
    } else if ( a == c && b > a ) {
        cout << a << " " << c << " " << b;
    }

    if ( b == c && a < b ) {
        cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
    } else if ( b == c && a > b ) {
        cout << b << " " << c << " " << a;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: If you use more variables and MIN / MAX functions, it will become much smaller and simpler

Comment: Have you passed all permutations of "1 2 3" to your program? Nobody can spot the wrong case on sight.

Comment: I suggest you to go a step back and consider that there are only 6 cases you have to consider (abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba). You need no more than 3 branches to cover all of them. Your code is more complicated than necessary

Comment: The shown approach is fundamentally flawed. I count seven `if` statements. The correct solution, working it out in my head, needs only three `if` statements.

Comment: `a == b && b == c` and `a == c && b == a` are equivalent (all three numbers are equal).

Comment: the question you didn't ask: How can I find the bug in my code? The answer: Write tests to see for which case your code produces wrong output, then use a debugger to inspect in detail where the code goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is smaller using the min/max functions but I feel like there might be a better way to find the **middle** value.

```
int min = std::min(a, std::min(b, c));
int max = std::max(a, std::max(b, c));

std::cout << min << " ";

int middle = a; // By default a, in case none of the following conditions is true
if (a != min && a != max)
    middle = a;
else if (b != min && b != max)
    middle = b;
else if (c != min && c != max)
    middle = c;

std::cout << middle << " " << max;
```

Comment: Oops, you're right

Comment: @idclev463035818 Are you sure `a == b == c` is UB? I think it's just wrong

Comment: @tuket It was before my edit

Comment: I would suggest `int middle = a;` instead of the `else`, just a matter of less shock when seeing a declaration without initializer

Comment: Ah, okay, now I see the edit. I thought you meant `if(a == b == c)` is UB. Sorry for that

Comment: @idclev463035818 You're right. I made another edit

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```cpp
int x[3];
// first we compute the smallest
x[0] = min(a, min(b, c));

// then the biggest
x[2] = max(a, max(b, c));

// finally we take the remaining one as the middle element. For that we use this substraction trick
x[1] = a+b+c - x[0]-[2];
// NOTE: if you are worried about overflow, you can use the following XOR hack:
// x[1] = a^b^c ^ x[0]^x[2];
// unlike with +/-, this is well defined behaviour (note that this is a problem only for `int`, `unsigned` overflow is well defined, so it would work even it overflows)

cout << x[0] << " " << x[1] << " " << x[2] << endl;
```

Comment: how about producing overflow when originally there is no need to add anything? This is not a good solution

Comment: @idclev463035818 Added alternative solution if overflow with UB is a concern (note that overflow is still possible if the input is bigger than the capacity of int)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the following sequence of if-else statements.

```
if ( !( b < a ) && !( c < a ) )
{
    if ( !( c < b ) )
    {
        std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << a << ' ' << c << ' ' << b << '\n';
    } 
}
else if ( !( a < b ) && !( c < b ) )
{
    if ( !( c < a ) )
    {
        std::cout << b << ' ' << a << ' ' << c << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << a << '\n';
    } 
}
else if ( !( a < c ) && !( b < c ) )
{
    if ( !( b < a ) )
    {
        std::cout << c << ' ' << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << c << ' ' << b << ' ' << a << '\n';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys but i haven;t covered yet the functions above.I must use only if, variable swap and else if.Also i entered values for each variable to test my conditions and they all pass the test.I scored 93/100 with my code, it works but i think it must be a better, more correct and cleaner version of what i did.